# Exception CX_SY_NO_HANDLER (type CX_SY_DYN_CALL_ILLEGAL_TYPE)

Tags: exception, abap

I have this particular error since the last Thursday and I could not find any solution, so I ask you guys if you know hot to fix it...

First:

I generate a CLASS (SE24) for download a pdf with a spool number.
Before that CLASS I generate a method to convert OTF -> PDF,

- In the parameters of the METHOD I declare 'I_IS_OTF' type C (IMPORTING) for check if OTF is 'X'
- 'I_SPOOL_ID' type I (IMPORTING) for write the SPOOL ID to transform
- And the problem comes here, I declare 'TABLE_BIN' type TABLE (EXPORTING) and 'SIZE_PDF' type I (EXPORTING).

The TABLE_BIN give me the 'Exception CX_SY_NO_HANDLER' and then explotes, but still read the SPOOL and give me information. I'm base in this code -> 'RSTXPDFT4'

I don't have a program to run the methods, I just use the same class.

THE CODE:

[image: PARAMETERS DEFINITION]

---

```
    CONSTANTS c_pdfcnv_pdfdst_xstring(1) TYPE c VALUE 'X'.

DATA: numbytes TYPE i,
      jobname  TYPE tbtcjob-jobname,
      jobcount TYPE tbtcjob-jobcount,
      pdf_stream TYPE xstring,
      pdf_stream_tab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF rspolpbi,
      pdfspoolid   TYPE tsp01-rqident.

 IF i_is_otf = 'X'.

  CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERT_OTFSPOOLJOB_2_PDF'
      EXPORTING
        src_spoolid                    = i_spool_id " Duda
        no_dialog                      = ' '
*       DST_DEVICE                     =
        pdf_destination                = c_pdfcnv_pdfdst_xstring
      IMPORTING
        pdf_bytecount                  = numbytes
        pdf_spoolid                    = pdfspoolid
*       OTF_PAGECOUNT                  =
        btc_jobname                    = jobname
        btc_jobcount                   = jobcount
        bin_file                       = pdf_stream
      EXCEPTIONS
        err_no_otf_spooljob            = 1
        err_no_spooljob                = 2
        err_no_permission              = 3
        err_conv_not_possible          = 4
        err_bad_dstdevice              = 5
        user_cancelled                 = 6
        err_spoolerror                 = 7
        err_temseerror                 = 8
        err_btcjob_open_failed         = 9
        err_btcjob_submit_failed       = 10
        err_btcjob_close_failed        = 11
        OTHERS                         = 12
             .

    IF sy-subrc NE 0.

    ENDIF.

 ELSE.
  CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERT_ABAPSPOOLJOB_2_PDF'
      EXPORTING
        src_spoolid                    = i_spool_id " eSTE
        no_dialog                      = ' '
*       DST_DEVICE                     =
        pdf_destination                = c_pdfcnv_pdfdst_xstring
        get_size_from_format           = 'N'
      IMPORTING
        pdf_bytecount                  = numbytes
        pdf_spoolid                    = pdfspoolid
*       LIST_PAGECOUNT                 =
        btc_jobname                    = jobname
        btc_jobcount                   = jobcount
        bin_file                       = pdf_stream
      EXCEPTIONS
        err_no_abap_spooljob           = 1
        err_no_spooljob                = 2
        err_no_permission              = 3
        err_conv_not_possible          = 4
        err_bad_destdevice             = 5
        user_cancelled                 = 6
        err_spoolerror                 = 7
        err_temseerror                 = 8
        err_btcjob_open_failed         = 9
        err_btcjob_submit_failed       = 10
        err_btcjob_close_failed        = 11.

    IF sy-subrc NE 0.

    ENDIF.

ENDIF.

  CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
  EXPORTING
    buffer        = pdf_stream
  TABLES
    binary_tab    = pdf_stream_tab.

 IF sy-subrc <> 0.
* Implement suitable error handling here
 ENDIF.


  table_bin  = pdf_stream_tab.
  size_pdf = numbytes.
```

[image: When the Gen.type change for SETST_TYPE_TABLE]

I already debugging this a few times, I only find the SY_TABIX give me '2'.

I tried using a try & catch, but still with the same error. 'Exception CX_SY_NO_HANDLER'.

[image: Exception gone but still with DUMPS]

Comment: I guess you mean that the line `table_bin = pdf_stream_tab` leads to an exception, so if you catch it (`catch cx_root into data(error)`) you'll get the right exception and message. Also, your issue is just about a value assignment, so if you indicate the actual type of `table_bin` at runtime (not the generic type `table`), it will be possible to answer. NB: for information of visitors, `pdf_stream_tab` has structured lines with 1 component of type 128 bytes.

Comment: Hi Sandra, I used the catch that you mention. The problem begin because the type TABLE is generic and pdf_stream_tab use TYPE RAW (I think is like a X). Maybe if I change the type TABLE for another value the method could start but what type I need to use 'cause the TYPE RAW - RAW128 give an error.

Comment: Please provide detailed information: what is the type of parameter `table_bin` at runtime? i.e. what is the type of the argument you pass to this parameter? Differently said, please post a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The type parameter of 'TABLE_BIN' -> TYPE TABLE

Comment: When the methods start the TP.GEN = TABLE but the TP.CONCRET give a SETST_TYPE_TABLE. The problem begin here...

Comment: Sandra, I already upload some screenshots to you or others to saw the parameters & dumps & etc...

Answer (score 2):

In the information you have given, you have used:

1. the type `SETST_TYPE_TABLE` for passing data to the parameter `table_bin`, which is a table of lines of type 70 characters,
2. and you tried to initialize it with the variable `pdf_stream_tab` which is a table of structured lines of type `RSPOLPBI` which is a DDIC Structure with 1 component of type 128 bytes.

As explained in the documentation below (I just indicate what is relevant to your case), this is not permitted, because the line types of the 2 tables are not convertible (the line types are respectively a field which is character-like and a structure which is not character-like).

Instead, as a PDF is made of bytes, not characters, you should always use variables "byte-like".

NB:

1. [ABAP Documentation - Assignment and Conversion Rules](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconversion_rules.htm)

   - [Conversion Rules for Internal Tables](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconversion_itab.htm)

     > "*Internal tables can be assigned to each other if their line types are compatible or convertible*"
   - [Conversion Rules for Structures](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconversion_struc.htm)

     - [Conversion between flat structures and single fields](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconversion_flat_elementary.htm)

       > "*If a structure is purely character-like, ...*"
       >
       > "*If the structure is not completely character-like, the single field must have the type c and the structure must begin with a character-like fragment ...*"
       >
       > "*No conversion rule is defined for any other cases, and assignments are not possible.*"
2. Here are the definitions of the above types

   - `SETST_TYPE_TABLE` in the type group `SETST` (transaction code `SE11` for instance):
     [image: SETST_TYPE_TABLE in type group SETST in SE11]
   - `Structure RSPOLPBI in SE11`
     [image: RSPOLPBI]